# How can I ensure a Unicode character is displayed correctly at all times?

Tags: html, css, unicode, glyph

For instance, the below will sometime appear as a square and a letter *u*, respectively. How can I avoid inconsistencies?

```
content: "\E07A"; // Shopping cart icon
content: "\1F50E"; // Search icon
```

By inconsistencies I mean displaying inconsistently on the same machine and same browser. Sometimes it loads correctly, and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: You must provide a webfont: you cannot rely on users to have a font which cover most Unicode characters: OS (especially old mobile OS) may lack of many fonts.

Comment: You need https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @tromgy this is as reproducible as it gets... I had no problem reproducing the inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: Have you investigated CSS unicode-range property?

Comment: Thanks @GiacomoCatenazzi Yes. Web font is provided and it works. The problem is it doesn't display correctly every single time.

Comment: @AHaworth No. I will look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load a font with that glyph in it (through @font-face), it will work consistently. When you don't, you are dependent of the fonts on the machine of the user. In that case you can better replace these 'icons' with [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) images, like this:

```
content:url('cart.svg');
```

Comment: Thanks JoostS. It displays inconsistently on the same machine and same browser. I agree replacing it with .svg is a safer bet. Thank you!

Comment: Then the page is probably (sometimes) not interpreted as UTF-8. But yeah... go for the SVG. It is much safer.